# entity framework linq query, get top N postIDs from favorite's table based on count

Tags: c#, database, linq, entity-framework

I have a database for keeping track of `Favorites` that looks like

```
[ID]
[PostID]
[userID]
[DateFavorited]
```

I'm attempting to write an entity framework query in Linq that will get the 12 `PostIDs` that appear the most often in this database.

I've looked at the documentation, but I'm just not putting together how to do this. The purpose is for a "most Favorited" page

I feel like there is an elegant solution, but I've frustrated myself to the point that I can't think of the way to do it without feting the entire table that that's a bad idea.

Comment: try count and group by and then take(12)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, this would be:

```
SELECT
    TOP 12
    PostID,
    COUNT(*) As FavCount
FROM
    Favorites
GROUP BY
    PostID
ORDER BY
    FavCount DESC
```

In Linq, I believe it would be:

```
var ret = db.Favorites.GroupBy(
    fav => fav.PostId
).Select(
    favGroup => new {
        PostId = favGroup.Key,
        Count = favGroup.Count()
    }
).OrderBy(
    row => row.Count
).Take( 12 );
```

With the type of `ret` being `IEnumerable<Anonymous{ PostId, Count }>`.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for the concise answer.